# jQuery ScrollTop not working on iOS

Tags: jquery, html, ios

I have a div that is scrollable within a page. When a button is clicked, the scrollable div should scroll itself to the form at the bottom (not scroll the body). My solution works fine on desktop, however, doesn't work at all on iOS.

Would be really grateful if anyone knows a fix for this please. I am running this off of the minified jQuery 3.3.1.

```js
    $('.reveal .detail-contact .button').click(function(){
      $('.reveal').scrollTop($('form').offset().top);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reveal">
      <div class="reveal-container">

        <div class="detail-heading">
          <h3 class="detail-title"></h3>
          <div class="detail-social">
            <img src="/img/facebook-f.png" />
            <img src="/img/instagram-glyph.png" />
            <img src="/img/twitter-logo.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="body-subheading">£$p>
        <p class="detail-description">
          
        </p>
        <div class="detail-contact ">
          <a class="contact-number contact-call" href="tel:+447971124144">
            <img src="/img/phone-icon.svg" />
            +44
          </a>
          <a class="button">
            CONTACT US
          </a>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <span class="minor-heading">KEY DETAILS</span>
        <div class="infographics columns is-tablet">
          <div class="column">
            <div class="infographic">
              <p class="minor-text">POWER</p>
              <p class="major-text"></p>
              <p class="minor-text">HP</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <div class="infographic">
              <p class="minor-text">TORQUE</p>
              <p class="major-text"></p>
              <p class="minor-text">LB-FT</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <div class="infographic">
              <p class="minor-text">0-62</p>
              <p class="major-text"></p>
              <p class="minor-text">SECONDS</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <div class="infographic">
              <p class="minor-text">TOP SPEED</p>
              <p class="major-text"></p>
              <p class="minor-text">MPH</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <span class="minor-heading">VEHICLE SUMMARY</span>
        <div class="tech-specs">
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">Registration Year</span>
            <span class="minor-text"></span>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">Body Colour</span>
            <span class="minor-text"></span>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">Fuel Type</span>
            <span class="minor-text"></span>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">Engine Size</span>
            <span class="minor-text">L</span>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">Gearbox</span>
            <span class="minor-text"></span>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">Body Style</span>
            <span class="minor-text"></span>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">Doors</span>
            <span class="minor-text"> Door</span>
          </div>
          <hr />
        </div>
        <span class="minor-heading">TECHNICAL SPECS</span>
        <div class="tech-specs">
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">Horsepower</span>
            <span class="minor-text"> BHP</span>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">0-62 mph</span>
            <span class="minor-text"></span>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">Drivetrain</span>
            <span class="minor-text"></span>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">Top Speed</span>
            <span class="minor-text"> mph</span>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="tech-spec">
            <span class="minor-text">Combined MPG</span>
            <span class="minor-text"> mpg</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-form" id="contact-form">
        <div class="reveal-container">
          <div class="detail-contact">
            <a class="contact-number contact-call" href="tel:+447971124144">
              <img src="/img/phone-icon.svg" />
              +44 7971 124144
            </a>
          </div>
          <h4>CAN WE HELP YOU?</h4>
          <p class="minor-text">
            If you have any questions about how we can help with this vehicle,
            please contact us via the form below.
          </p>
          <form method="post" id="enquiryForm">
            <div class="form-body">
              <label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" required/>
                <div class="label-text">
                  First Name
                </div>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" required/>
                <div class="label-text">
                  Last Name
                </div>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input type="number" id="telNumber" required/>
                <div class="label-text">
                  Telephone Number
                </div>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input type="text" id="emailAddress" required/>
                <div class="label-text">
                  Email Address
                </div>
              </label>
              <label class="textarea-input">
                <textarea type="text" id="enquiryDetails" required>Enquiry regarding</textarea>
                <div class="label-text">
                  How can we help?
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="field is-grouped-centered consent">
              <div class="control">
                <label class="checkbox minor-text">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="consentCheck" required>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Send Enquiry</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try put only one class in start of the script

‘’’
$(“.oneclass”)
‘’’

Comment: This does not make any difference unfortunately. jQuery is able to handle multiple selectors like CSS.